# Is there anyway to do a loop using Pytrends to automate data downloads

Tags: python, loops, export-to-csv

I am trying to collect data from Google Trends using PYTRENDS and just wondering how to automate the task of collecting data for many companies, and saving them in csv files. I managed to get to the following code which words well except for saving the csv files. This loop saves generates many files containing data for one firm only while it was expected to generate many one file per firm.

firms = ['Gecina','Covivio','Genesis Energy','Atland','Mercury NZ','Klepierre','Electricite de France','Nexity','Veolia Environnement']

for firm in cities:

```
  #build model
  pytrend = TrendReq(hl='en-US')
  keywords = [firm]

  pytrend.build_payload(
     kw_list=keywords,
     cat=0,
     timeframe='2012-11-01 2017-07-02')
  data = pytrend.interest_over_time()

  data = data.drop(labels=['isPartial'],axis='columns')

  data.to_csv('data.csv')
  files.download('data.csv')
```